# Get final location of a path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to create a function that takes a start location and a set of directions that a point travels on which includes which way it is facing. This is on a 2d grid x, y. All turning is a 90 degrees turn. Currently it can only move forwards and not backwards

```
location = [x, y, direction]

def path(location, directions):
    for i in directions:
        if i == "forward":
        else:
        # basically a bunch of if else statements
return final_location
```

An example would be:

1. `path([0, 0, North], [forward, forward, left])`

output: `[0, 2, West]`

Is there a better way than a bunch of `if/else` statements?

A better explanation of how the code should be run.

The start location is (0, 0) facing north. If you imagine a plot on a 2d x and y graph. it is facing north meaning face up, (positive y-axis direction), move forward to point (0,1) still north. Again forward so now it is at (0, 2) north. Now finally turn left (90 degrees). Now from the north turn left 90 degrees now you face west on point (0,2). So the output is [0, 2, West] –

What I want is to code it more efficiently for like any possible input, instead of having to code for each specific if else for future modifications. Like possible making it more complicated.

Comment: shouldn't the output be `[-1, 2, west]`? The last move was left...

Comment: @Tomerikoo maybe left and right are only for rotations and the rest for movement

Comment: @Tibebes.M makes sense... I guess OP should be more clear about that and provide all possible `directions`

Comment: @Tomerikoo the start location is (0, 0) facing north. If you imagine a plot on a 2d x and y graph. it is facing north meaning face up. while facing up (positive y-axis direction), move forward to point (0,1) still north. Again forward so now it is at (0, 2) north. Now finally turn left (90 degrees). Now from the north turn left 90 degrees now you face west on point (0,2) . So output is [0, 2, West]

Comment: Yes now I get it. I think that should be more clear and question and also you should provide the exact options for `directions` (can there be backwards?)

Comment: so what's wrong with the `if-else` approach? is it not working? is it ugly? is it slow? what is it exactly?

Comment: @Tibebes.M What I want is to code it more efficiently for like any possible input, instead of having to code for each specific if else for future modifications. Like possible making it more complicated like adding a second point along side the first.

Comment: @Tibebes.M Like possible making it more complicated like adding a second point along side the first and seeing if they collide

Comment: @Tomerikoo I for now it can only move forwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the natural alternative for big `if/else` structures (what in other languages can be achieved with a `switch` statement), is to convert conditions to dicts. Here it gets more complicated but here is an idea how to make the loop's body pretty generic and only rely on dicts constructing the conditions:

```py
def path(location, turns):
    new_location = {'x': location[0],
                    'y': location[1],
                    'orientation': location[2]}

    new_orientations = {'north': {'left': 'west',  'right': 'east'},
                        'south': {'left': 'east',  'right': 'west'},
                        'west':  {'left': 'south', 'right': 'north'},
                        'east':  {'left': 'north', 'right': 'south'}}

    axises = {'north': 'y', 'south': 'y', 'east': 'x', 'west': 'x'}

    directions = {'north': 1, 'south': -1, 'east': 1, 'west': -1}

    for turn in turns:
        cur_orientation = new_location['orientation']
        new_orientation = new_orientations[cur_orientation].get(turn, cur_orientation)
        if new_orientation == cur_orientation:
            axis = axises[new_orientation]
            direction = directions[new_orientation]
            new_location[axis] += direction
        else:
            new_location['orientation'] = new_orientation

    return list(new_location.values())
```

---

The thought process behind this is more or less:

- For each new direction (turn) we either stay in the same orientation (assuming there is no backwards), or move left or right. So we need to know for each orientation how it changes according to left or right. Otherwise, stay the same. We use a nested dict: for each orientation, for each new direction.
- Then, for each orientation we need to know which axis it affects (x or y). Again, a dict will tell us.
- Lastly, we need to know on which direction we are for each axis. Again, another dict.
- If the orientation didn't change (either forward or backwards) we do the logic to change the appropriate axis with help of the dicts. Otherwise, we just update the new direction.
- As you can see the input itself `location` was also converted to a dict for easier access and this is why in the end we convert the dict's values back to a list.

---

By adding another print inside the loop to get all steps and running `path([0, 0, 'north'], ['forward', 'forward', 'left', 'forward', 'right', 'forward'])`, we get:

```
[0, 0, 'north']
[0, 1, 'north']
[0, 2, 'north']
[0, 2, 'west']
[-1, 2, 'west']
[-1, 2, 'north']
[-1, 3, 'north']
```

Comment: Which variable would I use the print function on exactly?

Comment: You mean regarding the last section of my answer? I just added a `print(list(new_location.values()))` at the start of the loop

Comment: Thanks, I have learnt something new as I didn’t know switches where a thing